# Facebook graph api and reachestimate

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want some very code to work and it fails (probably) on wrong access token.
Step by step:
I trying this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/ in Graph API Explorer.
AD_ACCOUNT_ID is from AD Accounts overview.

First try: access token from my app, in development,marketing api added
Second try: in my app go to Marketing API->Tools->Access token permissions->All-> Generate

Response is always the same:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1357045,
    "message": "unknown error (empty response)",
    "type": "http",
    "status": 0
  }
}
```

Can i get reachestimate for an app in development?
Where to get a right token?

Comment: try the example url of the doc like `act_XXX/reachestimate?targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":["US"]},"age_min":20,"age_max":40}` in the graph explorer

Comment: i have tried with no success

Comment: this is the curl: `curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_XXX/reachestimate?targeting_spec=%7B%22geo_locations%22%3A%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22US%22%5D%7D%2C%22age_min%22%3A20%2C%22age_max%22%3A40%7D&access_token=<TOKEN>"`

Comment: it works! with access token generated inside Marketing API. So it was a graph explorer problem?

Comment: Very strange, probably a problem about encoding of the json passed in the query string. Can I post my comment as an answer so you can close your question?

Comment: yes, it will probably help the others, having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a problem due to the encoding of the json string, try this:

```
curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_XXX/reachestimate?targeting_spec=%7B%22geo_locations%22%3A%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22US%22%5D%7D%2C%22age_min%22%3A20%2C%22age_max%22%3A40%7D&access_token=<TOKEN>
```

Hope this help